# 'Log is not defined' error in fb share

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Iam trying to share a page of my website in facebook , for that iam using this function share:

```
var publish = {
                  method: 'feed',
                  message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
                  name: 'Connect',
                  caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
                  description: (
                      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
                      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
                      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
                  ),
                  link: 'http://fbrell.com/',
                  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                  actions: [
                    { name: 'fbrell', link: 'http://fbrell.com/' }
                  ],
                  user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about RELL'
                };

FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('feed callback'));//This line shows the error
```

But while running the code i get the error as Log is not defined. What is wrong with this code????

Comment: Where do you expect `Log` to be defined? It doesn't appear to be part of the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/v2.4)

Comment: Iam getting this error on console while running the code, i expect the code to share the details i have given  on fb.

Comment: I understand that however you haven't explained what you expect `Log` to be.

Comment: i got this code from http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed

Comment: i tried using FB.ui(publish) but then new window opens and shows "An error has occured"

Comment: `Log` appears to be some hand-rolled object created by the author of that page. You should probably avoid just copy / pasting code when you don't know what it does.